# GeoServer 2.16: Null object returned for expression: legend.width for setting value: 0 on: StyleInfoImpl[test_osm:rf]

Tags: geoserver, style, java, tomcat, css

I don't really understund how and why, but when I tried to save CSS changes on Style page of GeoServer GUI (by Apply or Submit)
I saw it:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access /opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/workspaces/test_osm/styles/rf.css

and next

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Null object returned for expression: legend.width for setting value: 0 on: StyleInfoImpl[test_osm:rf]

How to fix it?

Log output with WARNING and Errors:

```
Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@3611b9bf, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@5a3a2826, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@641c58ca, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@12270df4, org.geose2019-11-18 14:05:35,922 ERROR [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.getFileChannel(DiskDataStore.java:432)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.savePage(DiskDataStore.java:350)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore.storeData(DiskDataStore.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousDataStore$PageSavingRunnable.run(AsynchronousDataStore.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-11-18 14:05:35,955 WARN [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - Cannot save page with id '28' because the data file cannot be opened.
2019-11-18 14:05:41,391 ERROR [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.getFileChannel(DiskDataStore.java:432)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.savePage(DiskDataStore.java:350)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore.storeData(DiskDataStore.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousDataStore$PageSavingRunnable.run(AsynchronousDataStore.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-11-18 14:05:41,391 WARN [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - Cannot save page with id '29' because the data file cannot be opened.
2019-11-18 14:05:44,894 ERROR [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.getFileChannel(DiskDataStore.java:432)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.savePage(DiskDataStore.java:350)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore.storeData(DiskDataStore.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousDataStore$PageSavingRunnable.run(AsynchronousDataStore.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-11-18 14:05:44,894 WARN [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - Cannot save page with id '29' because the data file cannot be opened.
2019-11-18 14:05:51,921 ERROR [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.getFileChannel(DiskDataStore.java:432)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.savePage(DiskDataStore.java:350)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore.storeData(DiskDataStore.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousDataStore$PageSavingRunnable.run(AsynchronousDataStore.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-11-18 14:05:51,933 WARN [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - Cannot save page with id '29' because the data file cannot be opened.
2019-11-18 14:05:53,599 ERROR [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore/1281/8563/24AF3E9C32B8DCAA31613959CE13A029/data (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.getFileChannel(DiskDataStore.java:432)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore$SessionEntry.savePage(DiskDataStore.java:350)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DiskDataStore.storeData(DiskDataStore.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousDataStore$PageSavingRunnable.run(AsynchronousDataStore.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-11-18 14:05:53,602 WARN [pageStore.DiskDataStore] - Cannot save page with id '30' because the data file cannot be opened.
2019-11-18 14:06:01,244 ERROR [geoserver.web] - Error occurred saving the style
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access /opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/workspaces/test_osm/styles/rf.css
    at org.geoserver.platform.resource.FileSystemResourceStore$FileSystemResource.out(FileSystemResourceStore.java:309)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.writeStyle(ResourcePool.java:2212)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.writeStyle(ResourcePool.java:2198)
    at org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleEditPage.onStyleFormSubmit(StyleEditPage.java:126)
    at org.geoserver.wms.web.data.AbstractStylePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractStylePage.java:363)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1315)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor525.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting of tomcat is solution.
`service tomcat stop`
`service tomcat start`
I think unsaved style was stayed in java cache. But it just my hipotize.
**UPD**
A giant size of catalina.out in tomcat/log dir is reason. JAVA error like this could be alarm of out of memory for your JVM

Answer (score 1):

1. Check who owns `/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/workspaces/test_osm/styles/rf.css` and the styles directory, it **must** be writable to the user running tomcat (or jetty).
2. Check if the user you are logged in as has write access to that workspace (though that should give you a different error I think).
3. Turn logging up and look in the log file to see if there are any other errors.

Comment: 1- No 2 - No. About 3 I did it, and add output to question form. But I don't know what i have to do. Case user have access. It is a single user, I did this operation few hours ago.

Comment: does the file actually exist?

Comment: Yes. And tomcat is owner